# Microsoft Access 2007: Can I make Access behave like any other ad-hoc query editor?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Working with Access is a pain, imo.  I am used to ad-hoc utilities like Benthic, Toad, Oracle SQL Developer, SQLA, etc.  Microsoft Access seems like a child's toy in comparison.  I want a full-featured SQL editor that doesn't assume I am trying to create a view-style query whose sole purpose is to exist as a permanent fixture in my database that returns data.  I'd like to be able to write out multiple queries in a single pane and then hit F9 on the SQL that I want to execute.  I also would like to be able to indent my SQL.

Am I missing an advanced feature of Access or is this really as simple as Access gets?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly type in free-form SQL in the query builder (`Create` > `Query Design`, then click `SQL`).

You get this:

[image]

You are free to type in SQL in the format you want, which can include sub queries (such as the one shown in the above example).

If you're not going to save the SQL, then just build your one-off query in SQL view.  If you save your query, note that Access will re-format your SQL statements.

As an alternative, there are tons of SQL query tools that can work with ODBC, and thus should work on Access just fine.  I would try a few, find one you like, and then you can use it on all your systems from MySql, SQL, Access etc.

Access tends to be more of an end-user tool. So while you can type in raw SQL, most users in Access will as a general rule prefer to use the query designer in design view.

Comment: Assuming you looking at the SQL as per above the screen shot? Just type and edit the SQL - you don't even have to save and you can the simply hit the "!" (run) in the above from the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

adosqlconsole is a tool where you can run sql by hand against odbc databases. i've just used it and it's not too bad. much better than creating a query in a gui. some people argue that you can go into query design mode, then switch to sql view, then run the query and don't save it. To me that's just extra useless clicks and switching between mouse and keyboard for no good reason. I'm not sure the tool has all the features you want but it's a nice change from the access query builder rubbish.